# Building a simple android quote app

Tags: android, random, android-activity

New to android development.  I recently finished the lynda.com tutorials, but want to get more involved.  I was thinking about doing an app that shows various quotes from movies, but am in need of some guidance.  I just want it to have one activity and am going to have a next and previous buttons at the top.  How would I create the app that shows quotes in a randomized order and keep the quotes on the same screen?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: If you have A LOT of quotes, you need a db. If you have A FEW quotes, then you could use a string array, instead. In both cases, it's easy to take a random quote out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Create an SQL Database and store your strings in the table and display it using list view.

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ - tutorial for database.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is essentially just a basic layout question: Create a basic view, lay it out with a text field and two buttons. Create either an array list of strings or an SQLite database (as detailed by user3245033). You will then need to add listeners to both buttons (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html). The next button should generate a random number that becomes an index into the list or database storing your quotes, the back button should store the previous index value (so that you can go back to the same quote as opposed to a random quote). When you're retrieved your quote, set the text field to that string.

There are many basic examples that demonstrate this type of work. mybringback on YouTube particularly amazing:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3